# How to insert attribute to all child nodes

Tags: xslt, xpath, xforms, orbeon

Please find below my xform page.

```
<xhtml:html xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:xxforms="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/xforms"
    xmlns:exforms="http://www.exforms.org/exf/1-0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <xhtml:head>
        <xforms:instance id="instanceData">
            <form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
                xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
                <fruits>
                    <fruit>
                        <fruit-name>Mango</fruit-name>
                    </fruit>
                    <fruit>
                        <fruit-name>Apple</fruit-name>
                    </fruit>
                    <fruit>
                        <fruit-name>Banana</fruit-name>
                    </fruit>
                </fruits>
            </form>
        </xforms:instance>
    </xhtml:head>
</xhtml:html>
```

I would like to insert a attribute taste="good" to all fruit-name tags as below

```
<fruit-name taste="good">
```

I tried the following ways to achieve the same but it always inserts the attribute to first fruit-name only.

```
<xforms:insert ev:event="xforms-model-construct-done" 
  context="instance('instanceData')/fruits/fruit/fruit-name" 
  origin="xxforms:attribute('taste','good')" />

<xforms:insert ev:event="xforms-model-construct-done" 
  context="instance('instanceData')/fruits/fruit[position() &gt; 0]/fruit-name" 
  origin="xxforms:attribute('taste','good')" />
```

Please suggest a way to insert this attribute to all fruit-name nodes at shot.
Since the fruits list dynamic, we need to have a dynamic solution for it.

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a complete, short and easy XSLT solution. :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know XForms, but **this task is extremely easy with XSLT**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="fruit-name">
  <fruit-name taste="good">
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </fruit-name>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<xhtml:html xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns:xforms="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/xforms"
  xmlns:exforms="http://www.exforms.org/exf/1-0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <xhtml:head>
        <xforms:instance id="instanceData">
            <form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                  xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
                <fruits>
                    <fruit>
                        <fruit-name>Mango</fruit-name>
                    </fruit>
                    <fruit>
                        <fruit-name>Apple</fruit-name>
                    </fruit>
                    <fruit>
                        <fruit-name>Banana</fruit-name>
                    </fruit>
                </fruits>
            </form>
        </xforms:instance>
    </xhtml:head>
</xhtml:html>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced:**

```
<xhtml:html xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
 xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
 xmlns:xforms="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/xforms"
 xmlns:exforms="http://www.exforms.org/exf/1-0"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <xhtml:head>
    <xforms:instance id="instanceData">
      <form xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
        <fruits>
          <fruit>
            <fruit-name taste="good">Mango</fruit-name>
          </fruit>
          <fruit>
            <fruit-name taste="good">Apple</fruit-name>
          </fruit>
          <fruit>
            <fruit-name taste="good">Banana</fruit-name>
          </fruit>
        </fruits>
      </form>
    </xforms:instance>
  </xhtml:head>
</xhtml:html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `xxforms:iterate` [extension attribute](http://wiki.orbeon.com/forms/doc/developer-guide/xforms-other-extensions#TOC-Iteration-of-XForms-actions-over-se) is your friend here. The following will do the trick. And in this case, it's even simpler than XSLT ;).

```
<xforms:insert ev:event="xforms-model-construct-done"
               xxforms:iterate="fruits/fruit/fruit-name"
               context="." origin="xxforms:attribute('taste','good')"/>
```